# Get value of GridView Cell in RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I need to get the value of a cell from the RowCommand event, but the value is not in the PrimaryKeyNames parameter of the GridView.

Currently I have:

```
if (e.CommandName == "DeleteBanner")
        {
            GridViewRow row = gvCurrentPubBanner.SelectedRow;
            string BannerName = row.Cells[1].Text;
```

This doesn't work (index out of range error), I've also tried:

```
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
GridViewRow row = gvCurrentBanners.Rows[index];
```

This doesn't work either as the CommandArgument (the banner ID) is not the row ID.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
```

Then get the key or get the cell and cast to a datacontrolfield.

```
Dim id As Guid = GridView1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value

Dim email As String = CType(row.Cells(2), DataControlFieldCell).Text
```

Remark: this only works with Boundfields.

Comment: not solution with `asp:TemplateField - ItemTemplate` ?

Comment: refer @Chưa biết answer for Itemtemplate field.

Answer (score 6):

@Romil: your code in C#:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
    int id = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
}
```

*(LinkButton is button in template field).*

Comment: Valid for `asp:TemplateField - ItemTemplate`

Answer (score 3):

Try out this one..

```
GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
int rowIndex=gvRow.RowIndex
```

Comment: I dont see how that could work, as you're creating a new GridviewRow, not referencing the existing one in the gridview

Answer (score 3):

> int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

It only work when you use your button in Gridview is

```
<Columns>   
     <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Save"  CommandName="Select" /> 
</Columns>
```

I not sure this is correct but it work for me

Comment: This is the correct solution, as documented on the [MSDN page on `RowCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): _The ButtonField class automatically populates the CommandArgument property with the appropriate index value._

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit_Mob") {

        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow (((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

        int RowIndex = row.RowIndex; // this find the index of row

        int varName1 = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row.FindControl("lbl_mobile_id")).Text.ToString()); //this store the  value in varName1

        }
   }
```

Comment: there is missing a `)` bracket at `= (GridViewRow` in answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.CommandName == "EditDetails")
{
    mp1.Show();
    //LinkButton LnkEdit = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
    Panel1.Visible = true;
    Uploaddocs.Visible = false;
    Label lblmobile = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblN_MobileNo") ;
    Label lblDeathDate = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblDEATHDT");
    Label lblCAUSEOFDEATH = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblCAUSEOFDEATH");
    Label lblPLACEOFDEATH = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblPLACEOFDEATH");
    // Label lblRemarks = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblpracticalcredits");
    Label lblBank = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblBank");
    Label lblBranch = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblBranch");
    Label lblIFSC = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblIFSC");
    txtMobile.Text = Convert.ToInt64(lblmobile.Text).ToString();       //May be BigInt
    txtdate.Text = lblDate.Text;
    //ddlReasons.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(lblCAUSEOFDEATH.Text);
    //ddlReasons.SelectedValue = lblCAUSEOFDEATH.Text;
    txtcausedeath.Text = lblCAUSEOFDEATH.Text;
    txtPlaceofdeath.Text = lblPLACEOFDEATH.Text;
    BindBank();
    ddlbank.SelectedItem.Text = lblBank.Text;             //Sdents
    txtAddrBank.Text = lblBranch.Text;
    txtIFSC.Text = lblIFSC.Text;
}
```