# How to get the value of the label in an itemtemplate in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I hope you can help me with this one. I know this question is already asked too many times but the answer and the solution that I searched is not working for me.

I'm trying to delete a record in a database that is displayed in gridview.

I have an image button delete in gridview. when I click that the dialog box will appear asking if I really wanted to delete the record permanently and into the database.

Here's my code for asp

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" 
                    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="Silver" 
                    BorderWidth="1px" Width="100%">
                    <RowStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" 
                                    CommandArgument='<%#Bind("EMPNO")%>' CommandName="EditEmp">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgEdit" runat="server" AlternateText="Edit Employee" 
                                    ImageUrl="eHR_Images/edit.png" />
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField Visible="true">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" 
                                    CommandArgument='<%#Bind("EMPNO")%>' CommandName="DeleteEmp">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgDelete" runat="server" AlternateText="Delete Employee" 
                                    ImageUrl="eHR_Images/delete.gif" />
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Empno" SortExpression="EMPNO">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblempno" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EMPNO")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FIRSTNAME">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("FIRSTNAME")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LASTNAME">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("LASTNAME")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Entity" SortExpression="ENTITY">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblEntity" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ENTITY")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="LOCATION">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("LOCATION")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <PagerStyle Font-Size="9pt" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <div style="width: 100%; font-size: 10pt; text-align: center; color: Red;">
                            No record found.
                        </div>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="DarkGray" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" 
                        Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

and when I click the yes button the record will be deleted.

here's my code for `btnYes_Click`

```
 Try
        Dim firstname As String = DirectCast(gvUsers.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblFirstName"), Label).Text
        Dim lastname As String = DirectCast(gvUsers.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblLastName"), Label).Text
        Dim entity As String = DirectCast(gvUsers.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblEntity"), Label).Text
        Dim location As String = DirectCast(gvUsers.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblLocation"), Label).Text

        UpdateInsDelRecord("DELETE FROM emp_mastertbl WHERE empno='" & Me.lblRowVal.Text & "' AND FIRSTNAME = '" & firstname & "' AND LASTNAME = '" & lastname & "' AND ENTITY = '" & entity & "' AND LOCATION '" & location & "';" & _
                           "DELETE FROM empgroup_tbl WHERE SEQID ='" & Me.lblRowVal.Text & "';")

        'MessageBox("alert('Employee successfully deleted.');window.location='eHR_EmpMaintenance.aspx';")
        MessageBox("alert('Employee successfully deleted.');")
        Response.Redirect("eHR_EmpMaintenance.aspx?def_ent2=" + Me.ddlEntity.SelectedValue.ToString() + "&def_loc2=" + Me.ddlLocation.SelectedValue.ToString())
        Me.divDialog.Visible = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox("alert('Error occured during deletion.');")
        Throw
    End Try
```

code for rowcommand

```
If e.CommandName = "EditEmp" Then
        Response.Redirect("eHR_EditDetails.aspx?emp_id=" + e.CommandArgument + "&opt=opt_edit")
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "DeleteEmp" Then
        val_e = e.CommandArgument
        Me.divDialog.Visible = True
        Me.lblRowVal.Text = val_e
    End If
```

I'm trying to delete the employee's record that is shown in the girdview list
but there's an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: You are missing the event handler for RowCommand which will capture the clicking of linkbutton (`CommandArgument='<%#Bind("EMPNO")%>' CommandName="DeleteEmp"`) . Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, use sqlparameters instead of string concatenation, Refer [bobby-tables.com/dotnet.html](http://bobby-tables.com/dotnet.html)

Comment: This thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783962/get-value-of-gridview-cell-in-rowcommand?rq=1 should help you to get going

Comment: here's my code for rowcommand If e.CommandName = "EditEmp" Then
            Response.Redirect("eHR_EditDetails.aspx?emp_id=" + e.CommandArgument + "&opt=opt_edit")
        ElseIf e.CommandName = "DeleteEmp" Then
            val_e = e.CommandArgument
            Me.divDialog.Visible = True
            Me.lblRowVal.Text = val_e
        End If

Comment: Please update the question with all the relevant information. Also, where is the object reference exception pointing to?

Comment: I think it's not getting any value

Comment: Why is the code to delete data in `btnYes_Click` instead of rowcommand procedure? Which line is giving the object reference error? For delete confirmation, are you using client side or server side code? Why does the `<asp:GridView` tag does not refer to rowcommand event handler?

Comment: there's a dialog box that will appear and there's a btnYes_Click there so when I click yes the data will be deleted.